# Download Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

is it possible to download the scripts from firebase cloud functions.
I have a running script on it but I lost the file and now I can't update my function.

Answer (score 6):

Before we started working with Firebase Cloud Functions, we had set up a Google Cloud Platform account. Now whenever we deploy our firebase cloud functions, they are also accessible through Google's Cloud Platform.

Try using your credentials to log in here https://cloud.google.com/

See if you can access your functions under the the Functions tab.

If you can, you will be able to download the source for your project there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I can't see the code for this function. I only see an error that the archive can not be found. If I create a new function I can see the code. I have deployed the function with the node console